# 6/6/20 1:23:12.335 PM CylanceSvc[60]: CyHelperOSX.clientIsAllowedToConnect: bad signature status

Tags: macos, anti-virus

I am running Cylance 2.1.1553.503 on OS X 10.11.6

Every few seconds Cylance is generating these messages in my Console system log:

```
6/3/20 10:55:40.249 AM CylanceSvc[60]: CyHelperOSX.clientIsAllowedToConnect: bad signature status
6/3/20 10:55:40.250 AM CylanceSvc[60]: < CyHelperOSX.ClientConnectionHandler: error, client '(null)' (pid = 470) not authorized - cancel connection
6/3/20 10:55:40.250 AM CylanceSvc[60]: CyHelperOSX.xpc_connection_set_event_handler: ClientConnectionHandler(client) completed
6/3/20 10:55:40.251 AM CylanceUI[470]: client received event: <error: 0x7fff7c359b90> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff7c359f40> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}
```

Cylance Technical support doesn't know what's wrong.
I'm guessing it's a certificate issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From Cylance Technical Support:

```
This is a certificate verification issue directly related to El Capitan.  If you upgrade to the next version of macOS, the issue will go away.
```

and this ...

```
Q: Do you know any details about the cert verification issue?
A: Unfortunately, I do not have that information.  I do apologize.  I just know that this is an issue only with El Capitan and how to resolve it.
```